# How can I read the metadata from bitmaps in Android (Java)?

Tags: java, android, png, gif

How can I read the file format (png, jpg, gif, bmp, tiff, etc) and the width, height, and for those that have the value, the DPI for a bitmap?

Android does not have `javax.imageio.*` so the standard Java calls to read this are not available. [metadata-extractor](https://code.google.com/p/metadata-extractor/) is a good product but does not support `png` or `gif`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Width and height, along with bitdepth and color model, are not usually considered "metadata", rather they are basic image properties. By "image metadata" we usually refer to less essential data like physical resolution (DPI), EXIF-like data (timestamp, camera model, etc), etc; these are relatively format specific.

If you have decoded a image file (PNG, JPEG, GIF...) into a Bitmap, then you can ask the Bitmap object for the basic properties  (eg, [getHeight()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getHeight%28%29)).
But if you need to ask for some "metadata", which is format specific, a Bitmap object won't store that information, you need something like the metadata-extractor you linked.

For PNG, you can also use [this library](https://code.google.com/p/pngj/) (my own).

Comment: good point. Yes I just need those 4 image properties. And if possible, the bitmap format (png, jpg, etc.). Do you mean http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html and if so, is there a way to create one if I have an byte[] that is the bitmap file? Thanks

Comment: No, a Bitmap is a decoded image, it doesnt recollect where it came from (it could be created programatically, by hand). I don't get what you mean by `a byte[] that is the bitmap file` You mean a (encoded) image file in a byte array? That's totally different from a Bitmap object. a BitmapFactory will figure out the format and decode that into a Bitmap, but, sadly it won't tell you which was the original format. Do you need that?

Comment: I can do without the type - I can pull that from the signature. And yes, the byte[] is the image in a byte array. BTW, what call gives me the DPI? thanks

Comment: DPI is considered metadata, not all image formats support it, and there is no standard way to get it.

Comment: AARGH! Ok, is there a per bitmap format way of querying the Bitmap structure to get it? Thanks

Comment: You can't get something that does not exist. A PNG normally doesn't normally include a DPI, a GIF never does. And the Bitmap class does not include it.

Comment: I know a GIF never does. But a PNG usually does, a BMP/DIB can (it's rare) and I have never seen a JPG without it.